# Numpy Histogram over very tiny floats

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, histogram

I have an array with small float numbers, here is an exempt:

```
[-0.000631510156545283, 0.0005999252334386763, 2.6784775066479167e-05, 
-6.171351407584846e-05, -2.0256783283654057e-05, -5.700196588437318e-05, 
0.0006830172130385885, -7.862102776837944e-06, 0.0008167604859504389, 
0.0004497656945683915, -0.00017132944173890756, -0.00013510823579343265, 
0.00019666267095029728, -9.0271602657355e-06, 0.0005219852103996746, 
4.010928726736523e-05, -0.0005287787999295592, 0.00023883106926381664, 
0.0006348661301799839, 0.0003881285984411852]
```

(Edit: The whole array contains ~40k floats)

The numbers show the change of a measurement over time, e.g. +0.0001 means the measurement increases by 0.0001.

I'd like to plot a histogram over the whole array. Currently, `pyplot.hist` creates a plot which plugs all values in one bin ([This image shows the current histogram.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/op2lU.png), created with the following code (edited):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(20,20))
array = [] # floats here
axs.hist(array,bins=10)
axs.set_ylabel("Histogram of temperature/weight ratio")
axs.set_xlabel("Bins")
```

).
I guess this is due to the very small numbers - am I right here?

I tried using `hist, bins = numpy.histogram()` and plot this, with the same results. (Following this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17753501/numpy-histogram-representing-floats-with-approximate-values-as-the-same)).

How can I create a histogram over such small numbers, so that the values are distributed over e.g. 100 bins, and not all plugged into the first bin? Do I need to preprocess my data?

Comment: I just run your code and it does what it is supposed to do. Can you put an image of your graph?

Comment: For this small array the code is indeed correct. My final array however contains ~40k numbers. I'll clarify this in my question, thanks!

Comment: I am getting correct output, even with 50k numbers and values less than 10e-7. Maybe you have error while assigning values to the array. If you paste full code, it may be helpful.

Comment: Did you try to print the lenght of the y data in the histogram? (try this ```hist = ax.hist(ratio_temp_weight,bins=100)``` and then ```print(len(hist[1]))```. I don't see why the small numbers should be the problem. If you set ```bins=100```for example you should get that the length is 101.

Comment: Are you sure that it is the tiny floats the problem? Have you tried scaling your data and checked this issue goes away?

Comment: MNually specify the bins via the bins kwarg and a no array.  Ie. bins=np.arange(-0.01, 0.01, 0.0001)

Comment: @JodyKlymak , this solved my question, thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For other people looking for an answer:

As Jody Klymak suggested in a comment to my question, manually specify the bins.
I did not need to preprocess the data further, as I thought I had to do.

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import bumpy as np

array = [...] # large array with tiny floats

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(20,20))
hist = axs.hist(array, np.arange(-0.01, 0.01, 0.0001)) #numpy to create bins over range
plt.show()
```